# Convert a List<String> to a Set with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a one-liner to convert a list of String to a set of enum?
For instance, having:

```
public enum MyVal {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

and

```
List<String> myValues = Arrays.asList("ONE", "TWO", "TWO");
```

I'd like to convert `myValues` to a `Set<MyVal>` containing the same items as:

```
EnumSet.of(MyVal.ONE, MyVal.TWO)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26731123/3641067

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can make a `Stream<String>` of your elements, map each of them to the respective enum value with the mapper `MyVal::valueOf` and collect that into a new `EnumSet` with [`toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) initialized by [`noneOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#noneOf-java.lang.Class-):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myValues = Arrays.asList("ONE", "TWO", "TWO");
    EnumSet<MyVal> set =
        myValues.stream()
                .map(MyVal::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(MyVal.class)));
    System.out.println(set); // prints "[ONE, TWO]"
}
```

If you are simply interested in having a `Set` as result, not an `EnumSet`, you can simply use the built-in collector `Collectors.toSet()`.

Comment: Does that count as a one-liner these days :-) ?

Comment: Depends on the number of characters per line you allow. SO is stingy in that regard.

Comment: Instead of `Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(MyVal.class))` I'm doing `Collectors.toSet()` with the same result

Comment: @otonakav: you asked for an `EnumSet` explicitly. If any `Set` is sufficient, you can use `toSet()`, but then don’t ask for an `EnumSet`…

Comment: @Holger I've asked for a `Set<MyVal>` containing the same items as an `EnumSet`

Comment: @otonakav: maybe it’s just me, but the title of your question reads like “*Convert a List<String> to an EnumSet with Java 8*”. Clearly “to an **EnumSet**” Believe me, Tunaki knows that there is `Collectors.toSet()`; the posted solution `toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(MyVal.class))` is just for your specific question.

Comment: @Holger Tunaki changed the title of my question but it is not a big deal.

Comment: @Holger Actually, I rephrased the title to that because initially it was "convert to a set of enum" and since the OP said "containing same items as EnumSet", I "clarified" the title "convert to an EnumSet"... Looks like it wasn't true.

Comment: I suggest fixing the title and expanding the answer as `toSet()` clearly is easier to use when the type of the `Set` doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a two-liner (but shorter):

```
EnumSet<MyVal> myVals = EnumSet.allOf(MyVal.class);
myVals.removeIf(myVal -> !myValues.contains(myVal.name()));
```

Instead of adding elements present on the list, you could create an `EnumSet` with all possible values and remove the ones that are not present on the list.

Comment: Interesting. It has the slightly different property that it doesn't throw an exception if any of the strings doesn't match an enum. Might or might not be desirable, depending on the situation.